# Что в этом контексте означает слово "писать"?

Tags: значение-слов

> К сожалению, когда я начинал **писать**, я еще не знал, что плата залита лаком, так что извините уж…

Источник: [GT -- «Мой Тетрис — оборотень»](https://geektimes.ru/post/198246/)

Мне кажется, что здесь значение слова *писать* какое-то нетипичное. Или это просто опечатка?

Comment: Тут контекст нужен. Приводите более полный фрагмент текста или диалога. А бегать по ссылкам каждый раз - это только траффик делать вражеским сайтам..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

А может, автор начинал писать этот рассказ давно и имел в виду именно это: когда начинал писать, не знал, что плата заливается заводским лаком, а кто-то нашёл эту неточность (может, друг прочитал). Перепечатывать лень, просто поправил и извинился, там же и зачёркивания есть, как в черновике. Так что нормальное значение: "писать" по Ожегову - "2. составлять какой-нибудь текст, сочинять, создавать какое-нибудь словесное произведение 
Пример: П. письмо. П. отчет. П. роман".

Answer (score 0):

Не поленился, прочитал.
Там нет "другого" значения. Речь идет о написании данного поста или заметки - как там это у него называется.

Видимо, автор имеет в виду, что он забыл, что залил лаком для ногтей всю плату, поэтому фотки не будет. Чуть выше он об этом так и говорит.

Но вообще должен сказать, учить семантику слов по творениям интернетных авторов - не есть хорошая идея. Мало ли, что ему в голову пришло...